# How do I compute the local degree of the following map?

Tags: algebraic-topology, winding-number

I have the following porblem.

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ be a linear mapping, represented by a $2\times 2$ matrix. Moreover let the determinant be nonzero. Show that the local degree of $f$ at the origin is $+1$ if the determinant is positive and $-1$ if it is negative.

I wanted to start as follows.

*Let $A$ be te matrix that represents the linear map $f$ s.t. $\det(A)\neq 0$ and $f(x,y)=A\cdot (x,y)$. Let $U\in \mathfrak{U}(0,0)$ be a neightburhood of $(0,0)$ then it is clear that $f(0,0)\neq f(x,y)$ for all $(x,y)\in U\setminus \{(0,0)\}$ since $f$ is bijective. Now we know that $f$ restricts to a continuous function $F:\mathbb{S}^1\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2\setminus \{(0,0)\}$. Then by def $$deg_{(0,0)}(f)=W(F|_{\mathbb{S}^1},(0,0))$$Where $W$ is the winding number*

But I somehow from this point I don't know how to procede. Could someone help me how we can rewrite $F$ maybe?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is your definition of winding number?

Comment: But somhow our TA gave us a hint to try to rewrite $F$ as $F:\mathbb{S}^1\rightarrow \Bbb{S}^1$ and then $W(F,(0,0))=deg(F)$ but I don't see why one can do it

Comment: so he said that we don't need to know something about the winding number because he somehow spoke about $deg(F)=sign(\det(A))$, but I'm not sure and I don't see how to get there.

Comment: You will need **some** definition: Either of the winding number or of the degree of a map $S^1 \to S^1$.

Comment: but why can we write F as a map from $S^1\rightarrow S^1$?

Comment: You cannot do  this. However, the map $r :  \mathbb R^2 \setminus \{0\} \to S^1, r(x) = x/\lvert x \rVert$, is a strong deformation retraction. Then consider $\bar F  = rF\mid_{S^1}$. But without the definition of "winding number" it is impossible to say whether $\bar F$ and $F\mid_{S^1}$ have the same winding number.